# Copy final 13 lines of CSV to a new CSV

Tags: python, csv

My code appends the latest stock information for 13 companies into csv file (updated_quotes).  The quotes are added to the bottom of the file. I want to copy only the most recent quotes (13 lines) into a new csv file, which will only house the latest quote for each stock at a time. This will allow me to import only the most recent quotes into an excel file. Any ideas?

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from twilio.rest import Client
import os
import random

# list yahoo finance urls for desired stocks
yahoo_urls = ['https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EDJI?p=^DJI', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5ESPX?p=^SPX', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBUX?p=SBUX', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DIS?p=DIS', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BRK-B?p=BRK-B', 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NKE?p=NKE']

# loop for each stock with user-agent
for url in yahoo_urls:
    full_access = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.20 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.672.2 Safari/534.20'})

    # query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(full_access)

    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
    name_box = soup.find("h1", "D(ib) Fz(18px)")
    name = name_box.text.strip()
    print(name)

    #get the index price
    price_box = soup.find("span", "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")
    price = price_box.text.strip()
    print(price)

    # #Day Change
    try:
        change_box = soup.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataGreen)")
        change = change_box.text.strip()
        print(change)
    except AttributeError:
        change_box = soup.find("span", class_="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)")
        change = change_box.text.strip()
        print(change)

    # # open a csv file with append, so old data will not be erased
    with open("updated_quotes", "a") as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     writer.writerow([name, price, change, datetime.now()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `deque` tail recipe on a csv reader object.

I you have a header, keep that. Then use the [tail recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-recipes) replicated here:

```
def tail(filename, n=10):
    'Return the last n lines of a file'
    return deque(open(filename), n)
```

Calling `deque` on interator (like a file or csv reader or any other form of Python iterator) is equivalent to calling `list(iterator)` on the same object. But with a `deque` you can limit the size and create the equivalent of Unix's `tail` utility on that iterator.

Here is an example using a large range object and just keeping the last 5:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> deque(range(100000),5)
deque([99995, 99996, 99997, 99998, 99999], maxlen=5)
```

Comment: How should I write the final n lines into a new csv file?

Comment: If you can create some form of iterator that reads all of the relevant data (like in `soup`) you can run that iterator through a `deque` and use the result in a for loop or as input to `csv.writer` just the same as if your were going to write all of them.

Comment: hmm. Ok, I just started learning programming yesterday, so I'll have to do some research to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Don’t forget to close the file

Answer (score -1):

One *nasty* solution would be to just use `tail -n 13 updated_quotes.csv > last_quotes.csv`. You could invoke it via `subprocess.check_output("tail -n 13 updated_quotes.csv > last_quotes.csv", shell=True)`